# Bash, deleting specific row from file

Tags: bash, file, awk

I have a file with filename and path to the file
I want to delete the the rows which have files that do not exist anymore

file.txt (For now all existing files):

```
file1;~/Documents/test/123
file2;~/Documents/test/456
file3;~/Test
file4;~/Files/678
```

Now if I delete any of the given files(file 2 AND file4 fore example) and run my script I want it to test if the file in the given row exists and remove the row if it does not

file.txt(after removing file2, file4):

```
file1;~/Documents/test/123
file3;~/Test
```

What I got so far(Not working at all):
-Does not want to run at all

```
#!/bin/sh
  backup=`cat file.txt`
rm -f file.txt
  touch file.txt

  while read -r line
  do
    dir=`echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $2}'`
    file=`echo "$line" | awk -F';' '{print $1}'`

    if [ -f "$dir"/"$file" ];then
        echo "$line" >> file.txt
    fi
  done << "$backup"
```

Comment: I don't 100% get it, but you might want to change `done << "$backup"` to `done < "$backup"` first of all

Comment: Err... sorry, read that wrong. Since `$backup` isn't a filename, you can't redirect like that. I'd suggest either turning `$backup` into a filename, or doing `done < <(echo "$backup")`. The `<<` operator is used for HERE documents, not redirection.

Comment: As a note, I don't think the tilde '~' will be expanded in a shell script, I think it's treated as a string literal

Comment: Read through the input file, one line at a time. If the file indicated by the current line exists, add it to a bash array. At the end of the loop, overwrite the imput file with the array contents.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
while IFS=';' read -r file rest; do
   [ -f "$file" ] && printf '%s;%s\n' "$file" "$rest"
done < file.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.txt
```

or if you don't want a temp file for some reason:

```
tmp=()
while IFS=';' read -r file rest; do
   [ -f "$file" ] && tmp+=( "$file;$rest" )
done < file.txt &&
printf '%s\n' "${tmp[@]}" > file.txt
```

Both are untested but should be very close if not exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, this should do it.

```
touch file.txt file2.txt

for i in `cat file.txt`; do
  fp=`echo $i|cut -d ';' -f2`
   if [ -e $fp ];then
       echo "$i" >> file2.txt
   fi
done
mv file2.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Is there any way without using a second file?

Comment: @DennisVymer Yes, see my comment from 2 hours ago.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's crawling with bugs and anti-patterns so maybe that's the reason?